# Relative date human readable string like "Today at 5" to NSDate

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Is there a way using NSDate/NSDateFormatter (or other library) to convert relative date formats back to NSDate? I know NSDateFormatter has setDoesRelativeDateFormatting but I don't see that it goes backwards so I could use something like "today", "tomorrow morning" or "today at 5 AM" etc... to get a valid NSDate.

That's maybe too much to ask from Cocoa but maybe there's another library to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: All you have to do is write the code!